# A shorter way to express this? C = A if A else B

Tags: python

I find myself repeating this a lot:

```
val = x if x else y
```

Sometimes `x` goes several levels deep into a class or dictionary so it gets very long:

```
val = obj.elements[0].something if obj.elements[0].something else y
```

It looks ugly and forces me to type a lot more. Any known ways to shorten this? Perhaps a builtin like this exists?

```
val = first_try(x, y)
```

I guess I could easily write my own but was hoping for a built in.

```
first_try = lambda x,y: x if x else y
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `or` operator returns the first argument that converts to True:

```
val = x or y
```

E.g.:

```
>>> None or 'OK'
'OK'
```

Comment: And you can just keep chaining them! a or b or c or d

Comment: @Tony: Yes. Mind you, that's just a happy accident, not by design. `a or b or c` is equivalent to `(a or b) or c`.

Answer (score 1):

This to me seems like a case of trying to make code a little *too* terse.  I'd probably do something like this:

```
x = a.b.c.d[0]
val = x if x else y
```

One extra line, and a whole lot less to digest at once.

Comment: +1 This is a good solution for cases where something other than simple boolean testing is being used.

Comment: In some cases I use this approach. However, I generally like to avoid creating additional references.

Comment: @aaronasterling: This answer is identical to `val = a.b.c.d[0] or y` even if your types aren't simple booleans.

Comment: @Marcelo, Cantos. I said simple boolean testing - I didn't say that the types had to be booleans. The `or` replacement will fail for `a.b.c.d[0] if a.b.c.d[0] is not None or y`. I was just pointing out that `or` doesn't always serve as a replacement and this is one way that it can be done for more complicated cases.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Can you suggest values of x and y for which my code will behave differently to @Jason's?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, No, in the case of simple boolean testing, there is no difference and your case is preferred. For the case that I gave in my previous comment where something other than simple boolean testing is in play, Jason's is a good way simplify it. It would simplify to `x if x is not None else y` after the assignment.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Ah, now I get you. I misread your comment as, "fail for `a.b.c.d[0]` if `a.b.c.d[0]` isn't None or y." That totally threw me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) with the optional `default` argument.  In your long example above, this would be:

```
val = getattr(obj.elements[0], 'something', y)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. the question is not if `something` is defined or not (The original code will raise an `AttributeError` if it isn't) but if the value of it is truthy or falsy. This will return any value that happens to be defined regardless of its boolean status.